# Dual-boot Windows 7 & 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I partitioned my 500Gb HDD into two partitions, named the 2nd partition (200Gb size) "windows8", and tried to enter my Windows 8 OS on the 2nd partition -- but the OS didn't give me the option as to which partition to load it on.  I cancelled the loading and tried again but got the same result.  What can I do to resolve this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have EFI firmware and installation media is booted the EFI way but HDD is MBR style and no GPT partition or free space on a GPT disk can be found.

Check firmware settings how USB media or DVD media is booted.

If you have GPT formated HDD then installation media should be booted EFI way.

If you have MBR disk then installation media should be booted BIOS way.

Comment: How do you boot it *EFI* way or *BIOS* way?

Comment: By choosing option in firmware settings (only if you have UEFI capable firmware, if firmware is BIOS then you cannot boot EFI way)